# Создание самостоятельного файла в Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Пытаюсь создать exe файл через Clion. Но при запуске exe файла, выдает ошибку о нехватке dll файла. Как я понял, проблема в динамической линковке, но в CMakeList я нужную строчку добавил.

CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS})
```

Comment: И какого dll файла нехватает?

Comment: @VTT libwinpthread-1.dll

Comment: ну а почему вы пишуту, что все добавили, если вы не добавили то что нужно? Вам нужна `libwinpthread-1.dll` - и где она в вашем cmake?